# Redirect non-trailing to trailing version in squarspace website

Tags: squarespace

How to Redirect non-trailing to trailing version in Squarespace. Like an example

http://www.website.com/xyz redirect to 
http://www.website.com/xyz/

Answer (score 0):

Add 301 or 302 redirects by going to Settings > Advanced > URL Mapping

Format redirects like so :

```
/original/ -> /new/ 301
```

So you could do

```
/xyz -> /xyz/ 301
```